# IS Offloading Fortran to GPU with nvfortran on older GPU possible (CC61)

Tags: gpu, nvidia-graphics-card, nvidia

I am trying to use OpenMP to offload fortran code to a nvidia GPU using the Nvidia HPC SDK (https://developer.nvidia.com/hpc-sdk) and its nvfortran compiler.

The documentation (https://docs.nvidia.com/hpc-sdk/compilers/hpc-compilers-user-guide/index.html#openmp-use) for the current version states that to use the GPU features, you must have a GPU with compute capability greater than 7.0 (V100 generation of GPUs)/
My GPU has Compute capability of 6.1. **Is there a way to get the compiler to make use of my older GPU (Quadro P2200)?**

**Compiler error message**
:

```
~/source/arunprasaada/Youtube_Tutorials/Fortran_OpenMP/Hello$ nvfortran ./arr_add.f95 -mp=gpu 
nvfortran-Fatal-OpenMP GPU Offload is available only on systems with NVIDIA GPUs with compute capability '>= cc70'
```

**Quote from the documentation:**

Use the -⁠mp compiler switch to enable processing of OpenMP directives and pragmas. The most important sub-options to -⁠mp are the following:

- gpu: OpenMP directives are compiled for GPU execution plus multicore CPU fallback; this feature is supported on NVIDIA V100 or later GPUs.
- multicore: OpenMP directives are compiled for multicore CPU execution only; this sub-option is the default.

Are there other approaches for compiling fortran which can use OpenMP + Fortran to offload to GPUs that would support my gpu? I am hoping not to have to buy a newer GPU in this time of crazy prices and low supply.

Comment: “Is there a way to get the compiler to make use of my older GPU (Quadro P2200)?” - No; At least not with the current HPC SDK release.  The HPC SDK support is based on hardware support. You would have to obviously downgrade OpenMP

Comment: Going back to 20.7 it states that “OpenMP is not currently supported on NVIDIA GPUs. All target regions in an OpenMP 4.5 program are executed using the multicore CPU host as the target.” - You would have to determine what the minimum hardware is on that version or a later version.  Nvidia does not have anything earlier than 20.7 on their website.